# gulp keeping a sane source map after multiple processing

Tags: sass

I've optimized my css compilation for speed in gulp and essentially queued 3 operations together in one task. It works well but now I'm a bit stuck on generating proper sourceMaps.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified a bit your sample but you can try a solution similar to this one:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    filter = require('gulp-filter'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('default', function(){

    var lessFilter = filter(['**/*.less']);
    var cssFilter = filter(['**/*.css']);

    return gulp.src('src/**/*')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(lessFilter)
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(lessFilter.restore())
        .pipe(cssFilter) // Needed only in case the src folder contains files that are not compiled to css at this stage of the pipeline
        .pipe(concat('./final.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```